# How Multicollinearity affects the model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, linear-regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5R9a.jpg)

I took 4 features, all the features are the same X1=X2=X3=X4 and the target is Y=X1.

I am wondering, how multicollinearity affects the coefficients of the model?. I trained sklearn linear regression model with this data, It seems it does not have any effect on the coefficients. please help me to understand this.

Comment: Not sure I see a problem here: you have 4 identical features (`X1=X2=X3=X4`) so your model tells you they all have the same coefficient of `0.25` (1/4), that's what I would expect. Also you have `y=X1`, and you provide `X1=X2=X3=X4=10` and you get `y=X1=10`, that's also what I would expect. **What's the problem?**

Comment: Actually what I am trying to understand is, if X1, X2, X3, and X4 are the same. which means they all are perfectly correlated right? but still, the model gives the expected output. so what is the effect of multicollinearity here??. or am I not clear with the concept of multicollinearity?

Answer (score 0):

See to understand what is the problem with multi-collinearity we need to understand what is slope.Slope is nothing but how much y changes when there is unit change in x when rest of the features are kept constant.Suppose you want to predict y with two features

> y=m1*x1+m2*x2+b(ideal equation of line)

If there is multi-collinearity problem with above equation and if we try to change x1, eventually x2 will also change as they are correlated.This might create problem to calculate y(target variable) and may give a wrong answer.